# Fetchxml to get contacts with active opportunities having the current user as owner CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetch, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

Goal:  Make a view that can show all Contacts owned by the current user, and any Contacts with an associated opportunity owned by the current user.

Problem:  I don't have a great command of fetchxml or linkentities even after reviewing what I can Google about them.  When I try to build the view using my fetch statement it's not bringing back anything so I assume I've constructed it incorrectly.

Here is the statement I've made so far:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
                    <entity name='contact'>
                      //big list of attributes
                      <order attribute='fullname' descending='false' />
                      <link-entity name='opportunity' from='customerid' to='contactid' alias='aa'>
                       <filter type='and'>
                         <condition attribute='ownerid' operator='eq-userid' />
                       </filter>
                      </link-entity>
                      <filter type='or'>
                        <condition attribute='ownerid' operator='eq-userid' />
                      </filter>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>
```

Any tips would appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you just after a fetchXml query?

Comment: A totally new one, or to learn what might be wrong with mine.  Either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've checked CRM 2011 and CRM 2013.  With CRM 2011, this is not possible.  With CRM 2013, you can do this!

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
<entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' />
    <order attribute='fullname' descending='false' />
    <link-entity name='opportunity' from='customerid' to='contactid' alias='aa' link-type='outer'>
        <attribute name='name' />
    </link-entity>
    <filter type='or'>
        <condition attribute='ownerid' operator='eq-userid' />
        <condition entityname='aa' attribute='ownerid' operator='eq-userid' />
    </filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

You'll note, the alias referenced in the filter and you have to use an outer join.

I've added a blog post to provide a little bit of a walk through for anyone who is interested: http://paul-way.com/crm-2013-fetchxml-improvements/

Comment: Have you tried your code before you suggested it? I tried and I have got "Invalid XML." exception.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me on CRM 2013 online.  This is invalid on 2011; where are you running it?

Comment: Tried on one of CRM Online instances.

Comment: Works successfully on 6.0.2.50.  What is your online instance version you tested on?

Comment: 6.1.0.575 - both core and DB.

Comment: Ok, try again.  The closing fetch statement wasn't showing.

Comment: Now it works. Really interesting feature and it could be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Just saw this addition to the post.  Can't wait to get into the office later and try it!  Thanks for the suggestion Paul, I'll mark the answer as soon as I confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you would not be able to build this query using FetchXml. The workaround is to build report and embed it into your CRM.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <filter type="and">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="ownerid" operator="eq" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
          <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
        </filter>
      </filter>
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="opportunity" to="contactid" from="contactid" link-type="inner" alias="o_0" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Replace the `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` with current user Guid.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert of FetchXML, but I think this query is not possible.

This is the CRM explanation:

> related entity conditions or groups cannot be grouped with the parent
>   entity conditions or group

[image]

Comment: After some more searching around and experiments this is basically the conclusion I've come to as well.  It seems to pretty much boil down to that link-entities function like an 'and' filter.  And I need it to function like an 'or' filter.

Aw well.